# What are the allowed values for RDS ClusterParameterGroup family?

Tags: aws-cdk

I am trying to configure an Aurora PostgreSQL 2.3 cluster (compatible with PostgreSQL 10.7) but don't know what the rds.ClusterParameterGroup.family should be set to or if that even matters here.

The example I found used "aurora5.6" as shown below but I don't know how that corresponds to the PostgreSQL version.

```js
    const dbparams = new rds.ClusterParameterGroup(this, 'DbClusterParams', {
      family: 'aurora5.6',
      description: 'my parameter group',
      parameters: {
        character_set_database: 'utf8mb4'
      }
    });

    // create Aurora cluster
    const dbcluster = new rds.DatabaseCluster(this, 'DbCluster', {
      defaultDatabaseName: 'MySampleDb',
      engine: rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.AURORA_POSTGRESQL,
      masterUser: {
        username: 'myadmin',
      },
      instanceProps: {
        instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.BURSTABLE2, ec2.InstanceSize.SMALL),
        vpc
      },
      parameterGroup: dbparams,
      kmsKey,
    });
```

The API documentation doesn't provide any details. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-rds.ClusterParameterGroup.html

Answer (score 2):

You can find out more about the ClusterParameterGroup Family when taking a look at the CloudFormation Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbclusterparametergroup.html

The approach described there:

```
aws rds describe-db-engine-versions --query "DBEngineVersions[].DBParameterGroupFamily"
```

returns a complete list of possible values (with duplicates):

```
...
...
    "aurora-mysql5.7",
    "aurora-mysql5.7",
    "aurora-mysql5.7",
    "aurora-mysql5.7",
    "docdb3.6",
    "neptune1",
    "neptune1",
    "neptune1",
    "aurora-postgresql9.6",
    "aurora-postgresql9.6",
    "aurora-postgresql9.6",
    "aurora-postgresql9.6",
...
...
```